# Set texture grid or diamond view on a plane quad in Unity C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, gameobject

I am new to Unity C# and I changed material and this changes only the color of a plane.

But how can I have a texture like diamonds or ordonated triangles[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cqqF.png)

I managed to change material of  a quad/plane and this changes only the color of a plane.

But how can I have a texture like diamonds or regulated triangles

```
GameObject plane = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
plane.transform.position = centroid;
plane.transform.forward = new Vector3(0,90,0);
plane.transform.localScale = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);
plane.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = GreenMaterial;
```

Comment: well a quad is made of 4 points, 2 triangles. However they will be right angle triangles. You can define a mesh with your own triangles, and UVs etc, and make the shape you want, but you need to do that it is not a default in unity